# In RISC-V, why setting the `rl` bit on the LR instruction isn't necessary to make the LR/SC sequence sequentially consistent?

Tags: riscv, memory-model

*The RISC-V Instruction Set Manual Volume I: Unprivileged ISA* says:

> Setting the `aq` bit on the LR instruction, and setting both the `aq` and
> the `rl` bit on the SC instruction makes the LR/SC sequence **sequentially consistent**, meaning that it cannot be reordered with earlier or later memory operations from the same hart.

My question is: what prevents earlier memory operations from being reordered after `lr.aq`, breaking the sequential consistency guarantee, if the `rl` bit isn't set on the `lr` instruction? Shouldn't it be `lr.aqrl` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specification has been improved regarding this: https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual/issues/886

Answer (score 0):

The question is unanswered for long time. My answer may be not right. Hope someone can correct based on it.

I found one valuable resource [here p31](https://riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/14.25-15.00-RISCVMemoryModelTutorial.pdf), maybe helpful for your question.

There are two conditions `LR SC(earlier) SC` and `LR LR(earlier) SC`

And from official doc p50 -> 'An SC instruction can never be observed by another RISC-V hart before the LR instruction that
**established the reservation**.' and 'imply that a hart can
only hold one reservation at a time,' (also see doc contexts), so this ensure no `LR SC(earlier) SC` occurs

in p49, 'An SC can only pair with the most recent LR in program order' ('the most recent' ensures that related LR with SC always runs before SC) So Similarly if something like `LR LR(earlier) SC` occurs, the second LR will be considered pair with the last SC instead of the first.

Comment: Thanks for your time. The specification has been improved regarding this: https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual/issues/886

Comment: your link says 'RCsc ordering'. If so, then everything seems to not have misunderstanding at all. The [arm doc](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/102336/0100/Load-Acquire-and-Store-Release-instructions) says very clearly from my perspective about 'RCsc ordering'.